# WARNING: Application performed a reentrant operation in its NSTableView delegate. This warning will become an assert in the future

Tags: swiftui

SwiftUI on MacOS Ventura 13.4, version 14.3.1 of Xcode. I am developing (maintain) a pure SwiftUI/Swift GUI for rsync. I have two versions, one Swift/Storyboard and SwiftUI/Swift.. Both apps are stable.. I have just commenced replacing all `list`and `foreach` with SwiftUI `table` within the SwiftUI app. The data for all tables are computed properties and every time number of lines in table is more than about 200 rows, Xcode throws the above warning... All tables are quite simple, no fancy stuff or formatting.. But warning is consistent...

I have googled around but no solution found? Has anyone solved the issue? Or know what causes the issue?

Comment: Facing the same issue in July 2023.

Comment: According to a reply on Apple Developer forums, even [Apple's official sample apps are facing the issue](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/720332?answerId=750438022#750438022). And no one came with a solution. Most likely an Apple bug in my opinion, and you could try opening a FeedbackAssistant to them.